# Force HTML Tables To Not Exceed Their Containers' Size

Tags: html, css, html-table, column-width

This question has been asked several times, but none of the answers provided seem to help me:

See this in action here: **http://jsfiddle.net/BlaM/bsQNj/2/**

I have a "dynamic" (percentage based) layout with two columns.

```
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
.grid .col50 {
    padding: 0 1.5%;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

In each of these columns I have a table that is supposed to use the full column width.

```
.data-table {
    width: 100%;
}
.data-table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

My problem is that some of the columns in that table have content that needs to be truncated to fit in the given width of the table. That does not happen, though. I get two tables that are overlaying each other.

Requirements:

- Needs to be percentage based. I can't set absolute sizes.
- Each rows' height must not grow beyond one text line (which would happen if I remove white-space: nowrap)
- Must work in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 8+
- Can't display tables below each other as it has to fit onto one sheet of paper when printing.

What I tried:

- inside of  and use width and overflow on that. Changed nothing.
- "display: table;" on containing div - instead of having two columns the tables were displayed below each other
- "table-layout: fixed;" - Forced all columns to have same width
- I know that columns 2+3 have a total of 30% of width so I tried to manually set column 1 to 70% - Did not change anything
- [Zero-width spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650928/999) in content - didn't change anything, probably due to white-space: nowrap;

Related Questions:

- [Table width exceeds container's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531867/table-width-exceeds-containers-width)
- [How do I prevent my HTML table from stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183676/how-do-i-prevent-my-html-table-from-stretching)
- [HTML CSS How to stop a table cell from expanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236148/html-css-how-to-stop-a-table-cell-from-expanding)
- [Table Overflowing Outside of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259189/table-overflowing-outside-of-div)

Comment: Couple thoughts here. If you have to have some of the text cut off, overflow:hidden; basically cancel's out that effect so if there was extra text then it will get hidden. I'm not sure I understand the point of a) keeping all in one line and having some of the lines cut off (not hidden) and b) having more than one table overlay each other.

Comment: a) I don't want those tables to overlap. That's exactly what I want to avoid. b) I'm okay to truncate the text at the point where it does not fit into the table's width. c) Why is there always somebody asking "WHY" on this site even when it does not help to solve the problem? ;)

Comment: @BlaM Asking why is a means of ascertaining what variants of solutions the OP would accept.

Answer (score 82):

you need to add the table-layout property:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

also include width=100% in the table HTML tag, not just the style tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/reeK5/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This works well regardless of width value, but I only tested with percentage widths.

Comment: Why do you include `width="100%"` in the HTML tag?

Comment: @swenedo Styles as attributes in an HTML tag are 'in-line' styles, and they take precedence over any styles in the `<head>` element or in any external stylesheets. It is a way to ensure that the table is set to `width: 100%;` rather than something different like `width: auto;` declared elsewhere.

Comment: Per MDN wrt to `width` attribute: _"Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated."_  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table -- furthermore, it's unnecessary.

Comment: That makes all columns the same width, which is not what I'm after. There no need to allocate the same width to columns containing numerical values as to the columns with large text

Comment: Thanks really a lot! I've been looking for this for hours!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you'll be interested in a `max-width: 0;` hack I've discovered.

It has some limits, we should use CSS tables instead of HTML, but it works:

```
.leftBlock
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rightBlock
{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CyberAP/NUHTk/103/

Comment: I found that the effect of max-width and min-width on tables and their parts is explicitly undefined by the CSS 2.1 spec. So any related behavior likely cannot be depended on. Still interesting to know.

Comment: There's not table tag in your example. The topic starter specifically asked about html tables.

Comment: Yet another incomprehensible logic of `max-width` of CSS. But it indeed work, at least in my case. So horrifying.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.div {
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.breaked {
  word-break: break-all;
}
table{
  border:1px solid red;
}
td {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaa_________________________________________-sdasd-ad-f-asfas-df-a a-sd-fa-d-ad-fa-ds-asd-a-ads-fa-df-ads-fa-d-fad-f-ad-fad-ad-sa-fda-df-</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ddddddddddddd</td>
    <td>aa</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <br /><hr/><br />
  <table class="breaked">
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaa_________________________________________-sdasd-ad-f-asfas-df-a a-sd-fa-d-ad-fa-ds-asd-a-ads-fa-df-ads-fa-d-fad-f-ad-fad-ad-sa-fda-df-</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ddddddddddddd</td>
    <td>aa</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Only works with text tables, not tables containing complex data.

Answer (score 2):

Measurements on tables work differently. In general, width on a table cell is handled as min-width.

One solution, if you don't mind adding extra markup, is to put a `div` inside each table cell in which you put the content. Then give this div a width, or a max-width. So

```
<td>http://www.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/xxx_xxxx/XXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/XXXXXXXX_xXxxxx</td>
```

becomes

```
<td><div>http://www.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/xxx_xxxx/XXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/XXXXXXXX_xXxxxx</div></td>
```

and so on.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bsQNj/4/

Edit: I see the fiddle needs some work - I forgot to put some divs in where they were necessary. But I hope you can work with this idea.

Comment: I can only work with percentage based widths because I can never know how wide the column will be. When I use 10em it may be too narrow or too wide. Giving the <div> a percentage based width does not help, though.

Comment: Sorry, but like I said in my edit, I hadn't added divs to all the tds. Still hope you can work with the idea though.

Comment: Missing divs is not the problem. "max-width: 10em" is the part not helping me. The column may be 100em wide or it may be 5em wide. That depends on the screen-/paper-size, and I don't know beforehand. I could try to figure it out with javascript, but it feels like a dirty hack to me ;)

Comment: The 10em was just an example. Just like your fiddle was just an example. Apply the size you need to the divs in the tds instead of the tds themselves. Ther problem is not that I want your columns to be 10em wide, but that tds refuse to shrink to whatever width you give them. Here's a fiddle I made earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/HnB3G/3/

Comment: My problem is that the width I want is "as wide as possible". I **can't** use absolute values - such as px, pt, em - because I don't know how wide the table will be. It's all just percentages.

Answer (score -4):

In your CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That should cover all tables

Comment: Nothing changes when I add this.

Comment: Won't work if your tables have fixed widths declared in the html (ie width="500px")